# How to manage source code repositories for scheduled release, development and research

Tags: mercurial, release-management

We have Mercurial version control system and we are having difficulties managing the release for mandatory features, optional features and research. We have two separate repositories, one for release and one for development.

We have scheduled deployment every quarter. So we develop features (mandatory and optional) for three months, and testers test the features on Dev site (continuous build).

At the end of release cycle we have to take mandatory and optional features (QA passed only) from development repo and manually copy them into release repo. We cannot merge the development repository into release and have to copy files manually because, at the time of release there could be un-tested/un-developed features/code in development repository. We then build out Test site from release repository and have testers do full testing there. If there are any issues found these are fixed in release repo first and the the release repo is merged into development repo.

However, because of manual merge, there is a chance of copying unwanted changes/files into release repo and cause issues.

Can someone please advise how to get rid of this manual copy paste using Mercurial? I am sure this is a standard process for a development company and there should be a better process to handle this.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you're treating a distributed version control system as through it was a centralized version control system with a linear history. You should embrace the tree-like structure of the version history.

Comment: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 0):

You must make feature development from release points. Never on `tip` or from random points:

```
v1 ----- v2 -- v3 --> v?
|\      //    /
|\f1 ---/    /
|\f2 ---    /
| f3 -------
f4 ------------------>
```

`f...` are features development. `v...` are points after successful merging/testing sets of features (strictly speaking it's a tag, but for maintaining release fixes you may use named branches).

In example I select features `f1` and `f2` for `v2` release by merging/testing/fixing to `v2` branch or `default` branch with tag `v2` changes that in `f1` and `f2` branch. If I found bug in `f1` I fix it in `f1` and then merge to `v2'` and `v3'`.

`f3` feature ready for shipment only in `v3` release. While we still consider `f4` isn't safe for shipping.

Essential part - properly choose point from which you start implement feature. If you select too early `v` point - some features may be missed in source code tree, if you select too late and will be asked to deliver feature in early release `v0` - you must backport your features without support from `DVCS` tool.

You can't develop feature on top of another feature, only on top of features joint points.

This is similar to patch-management but we try to keep merge history so further merges would easy as we have clean directional feature-relation graph.

Also you ask to avoid cherry-picking of "features". That term usually associated with bugs picking which is possible to avoid by finding by `bisect` first changeset that introduce bug, fix bug on top of that changeset and merge to all necessary branches that fix.

Or just fight with cherry-picking like you do now as very unlikely it is easy adopt development/release model to such wired. SVN branch model (implementation specific) very close to that you are doing with Mercurial.